# DIVs inside TinyMCE no longer editable in IE9/10 after MS updates

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, content-management-system, tinymce

after a windows update, elements within TinyMCE cannot be selected or edited when viewed in internet explorer

here's the code being used:

```
<textarea name="fullT" style="width:1040px; min-height:350px;">
    <div cstyle="position:absolute; right:0; resize:none; min-height:250px; text-align:left; float:right; width: 265px; margin: 0; padding:0 0 0 20px;">
        <h2>Side column</h2>
        <p>When it has a width and/or min-height, and floats is not editable.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="min-height:250px; text-align:left; float: left; padding:0; width:705px; margin:0; border:0; position:absolute; left:0; resize:none;">
        <h1>IE issue</h1>
        <p>Not editable when it has a width and/or min-height</p>
    </div>
</textarea>
```

Comment: After *which* "windows update" specifically do you see this? Do you have a repro URL that others can look at?